# Loop works only if there is one row returned

Tags: php, loops

I'm querying a db with this command:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE country = '$_SESSION[country]' AND city = '$_SESSION[city]' ORDER BY id DESC");
if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 1) {
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "OK";
    $n = 1;
    echo '<div class="control-group">
          <div class="controls">
          <label class="checkbox">
          <input type="checkbox" name="users" value="'.$row['id'].'" onclick="\'chkcontrol('.$n++.')\';">'.$row['name'].'
          </label>
          </div>
          </div>';
  }
}
```

It returns True (works) if I have only one row in the table. If I add another one, it returns False. What am I missing?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 2):

`if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 1)`  has to be `if(mysql_num_rows($result) >= 1)` for sure.

Otherwise the `if` will only be true (and loop entered) when `mysql_num_rows($result)` is exactly 1.

Solved.

Comment: Or just `if (mysql_num_rows($result)) {` really.

Answer (score 0):

Your query with the session variables seems incorrect, it should be

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE country = '{$_SESSION['country']}' AND city = '{$_SESSION['city']}' ORDER BY id DESC");
```